# I have this error in Django regarding a failed test

Tags: python, django

It says that 1 test has failed in the tests.py file in the HomeTests. I am doing a product application.  Here is my tests.py file.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import resolve
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import home, product_topics
from .models import Product

class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('home')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
        view = resolve('/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, home)

    def test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
        product_topics_url = reverse('product_topics', kwargs={'pk': self.product.pk})
        self.assertContains(self.response, 'href="{0}"'.format(product_topics_url))

class ProductTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Product.objects.create(name='Light Bulb', description='Conserver energy',price=25.99,qtyOnHand=25)

    def test_product_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('product_topics', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_product_topics_view_not_found_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('product_topics', kwargs={'pk': 99})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 404)

    def test_product_topics_url_resolves_board_topics_view(self):
        view = resolve('/products/1/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, product_topics)
```

The AttributeError says that HomeTests has no attribute Product.

and here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Product

# Create your views here.

    def home(request):
    
        products = Product.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'products': products})
    
    def product_topics(request, pk):
    
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'topics.html', {'product': product})
```

In the urls.py, I have the following.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from inventories import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.product_topics, name='product_topics'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I would like to know why I am getting this error and what this error means so I can fix it. I am following the tutorial at [Urls](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/18/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-3.html#using-the-urls-api)

Comment: The test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self) for failing and I don't know what to do.  I followed the instructions with my Product model. If someone can show me how to fix it, I'd be glad.

Comment: I was able to find the solution.  It turns out that it's best not to do programming under high levels of stress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the whole of this test!

```py
def test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
    product_topics_url = reverse('product_topics', kwargs={'pk': self.product.pk})
    self.assertContains(self.response, 'href="{0}"'.format(product_topics_url))
```

There is no `product` or `response` objects in `self` while you are calling `self.response` & `self.product`. Maybe you wanted to do something like this?:

```py
from django.test import Client


class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    # the other tests

    def test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
        product = Product.objects.create(
            name='name', description='descr', price=1.0, qtyOnHand=2
        )
        product_topics_url = reverse('product_topics', kwargs={'pk': product.pk})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
        self.assertContains(content, 'href="{0}"'.format(product_topics_url))
```

Comment: That what I was thinking.  I was following the tutorial, but apparently skipped some steps.  Thanks for pointing that out. I was able to get it to work.